# How to remove a JavaScript initialisation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, conflict, conflicting-libraries

What I am trying to achieve is a second dropdown list to be populated with values based on the selection of the first dropdown list.

I've got it to work using the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/ydPfH/6/

The problem is that an external plug in that I am using to display images in a drop down list somehow stops this code from working properly.

The code that initalises this plug-in is `$("body select").msDropDown();` and what I have below the simple search form that uses this plug-in is a jquery expandable div so you click `Advanced Search` to expand the form with the dynamic dropdowns.

```
<a href="#" rel="toggle[advancedsearch]" data-openimage="images/collapse.png" data-
closedimage="images/expand.png">Advanced Search<img id="expand" 
src="images/collapse.png"/>   </a> 
<div id="advancedsearch">
<p>Document Properties:</p>
<form>
<select id="tags" name="tags" class="tags">
etc....
```

What I'm hoping for is some kind of `onclick` or something even easier to call to another JS method to somehow remove the `$("body select").msDropDown();` initialisation or to even initialise something silly that in turn removes it.

Full source of the page can be seen here if it helps: http://jsfiddle.net/pQ9LT/

Thanks,

Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm getting this right, here is the answer:

You should add `class` attributes to the `<select>` elements that are going to be using your msDropDown plugin. Then initialize the plugin like this `$('select.yourClass').msDropDown();` 
where `yourClass` is the class name you assigned these `<select>` elements.
The `body` part in your selector is superflous.

This way, jQuery will only apply the plugin to the `<select>` elements "marked" with you class name and not all of them so you can use the other "normal" `<select>` elements without interference.

Hope I helped you out.

Comment: Thank you very much Tom, you have no idea how grateful I am - I can imagine how difficult it was to try and follow my question to an outsider. 

You're a star!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely clear on what your overall requirements are and what may or may not be acceptable so where are a few thoughts that I have.

1. Give the select elements you *do not* want styled as image combo boxes a `class` or an `id`. Then use the [:not() selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) in combination with your `msDropdown` initialization

   ```
   $("body select:not('.nostyle')").msDropDown(); //using the class 'nostyle' to filter out the elements that should get the image combobox
   ```
2. Use a more specific selector in the initialization call; this is kinda the opposite of the above

   ```
   $("body select.classOfSelectsTobeStyled").msDropDown(); //using the class 'classOfSelectsTobeStyled' on elements that should get the image combobox
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and for your time. I tried your answer first but it didn't seem to work for me but I have certainly learned something new, thanks, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Glad to be of help. I realized that I had an error in my script - there was a space between `select` and `.classOfSelectsTobeStyled` in the second suggestion (which is otherwise pretty much the same thing that Tom suggested before). The space changes the selector to look for descendents of `select` elements that have that class. Without the space, it's selecting descendents of `body` that are `select` tags *and* have the class `.classOfSelectsToBeStyled`